# add default item to RadComboBox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to add default item as 'All' at top of RadComboBox. How can I do this? I am using LoadOnDemand and loading database items using WCF service.Please help. I am stuck with this.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can set the "EmptyMessage" property of the RadComboBox to "All". Take a look at [this Telerik demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/loadondemand/wcf/defaultcs.aspx) for an example.